# AppBar back button animation clashes with title when navigating between screens

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design, flutter-appbar

I'm having issues with Flutter's AppBar backwards navigation button clashing with my centred title when navigating between screens.

[image: Example of problem]

As you can see the arrow moves through the title when going forward/back within the navigation.

How can I only show the back button gracefully for the last moments such that it doesn't clash with the title? This would have to be for both forwards/backwards navigation.

Here is my code for the AppBar:

```dart
AppBar(
  centerTitle: true,
  title: const Hero(
    tag: 'logo',
    child: Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 27,
        child: Text(
          'Some App',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Note my use of `Material` in the `Hero` widget is a fix for [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20845#issuecomment-479022109) issue.

Things I've tried:

- Using an expanded widget within the title with a solid background such that the arrow cannot be seen while passing the title. The problem here is that the title then becomes off-centre when the widget shows the back button. Also the arrow still appears briefly on the right.
- Removing the back button with `automaticallyImplyLeading: false`. This is not an option as we want a visual cue for navigation.
- Setting the duration (in Go Router) of the animation to zero. Again, this is a less than elegant user experience.